# How can I access child widgets in the C++ parent of this Widget Blueprint

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Here is a screenshot of the Blueprint editor for my CharacterSelectMenuWidget blueprint. This Blueprint's parent is a C++ class that extends a UUSerWidget.

Blueprint Editor Screenshot
[image: Blueprint Editor Screenshot]

The TeamSelectorWidget and RoleSelectorWidget are both Blueprints of type BinaryOptionSelectorWidget. That Blueprint's parent is a C++ class called UBinaryOptionSelectorWidget. I want to grab a reference to the TeamSelectorWidget and the RoleSelectorWidget that are children widgets of this blueprint's canvas inside the C++ class. I've tried the following, but this does not work

```
UBinaryOptionSelectorWidget TeamSelectWidget = Cast<UBinaryOptionSelectorWidget>(GetWidgetFromName(FName("TeamSelectorWidget")));
```

I may have the class casting wrong, though I'd expect to see some sort of error message if that were true. I can't use the Visual Studio debugger to evaluate the expression and debug that way, because it complains about the constructor for FName() (is that a known issue).

If anyone has an idea of how to access these variables, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is add `meta = (BindWidget)` inside of a `UPROPERTY()` macro that is linked with a widegt variable in your C++ header. Like so:

```cpp
UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, meta = (BindWidget))
class UBinaryOptionSelectorWidget* TeamSelectorWidget = nullptr;
```

That's it! Allows easy native access to blueprint defined widgets!

This will do some magic behind the scenes and will automatically find and assign the widget in the blueprint derived class to this C++ variable. So you don't need to manually set this, which is pretty neat!

The type and name of this C++ variable must match exactly with what you have in your widget hierarchy. Notice how these name are the same as what you see in the widget blueprint.

Reason being that, the `BindWidget` meta property requires a widget be present in the widget hierarchy for it to work or else you will get a blueprint compile error.

Alternatively, you can use `BindWidgetOptional` and UE4 will not complain if it couldn't find the widget in the hierarchy. So that means it can possibly be `nullptr` so when you access it make sure to check if it is valid. You don't need to do this with `BindWidget` as it's basically guaranteed to be valid (if it could find it that is).